# Unable to connect to Airlive Wireless AP through Ethernet

Tags: 11.10, hardware, wireless-access-point

This is crazy. I've connected the Airlive WL5460AP with an ethernet cable to the computer. The computer detects the access point, but doesn't establish connection. The LAN port is LAN1 according to the manual.

The Service Line told me to configure my PC with a specific IP address 192.168.100.xxx where xxx shouldn't be 252 (reserved to the AP). I changed the /etc/network/interfaces file according to [this link](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/319). But still, Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't connect.

The Service Line told me to try with Windows under VMWare, but after trying, I think that VMWare makes use of the underlying Linux kernel.

So, any idea how to establish connection to this Linux unfriendly hardware?

Oh, the idea I have is to have a universal repeater of the existing ISP router signal. I also tried to wire the AP directly to the router, but without success (maybe I should have used a special LAN port).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a new interface with the settings they suggest:

- (right-click) on Network icon (up/down arrows)
- select Edit Connections
- click on 'Add' for wired

  enter the name for this new connection
- select 'IPv4 settings'

  method: 'Manual'
- Addresses: 'Add'

  fill in the numbers  (per image below)
- click 'Save'

***This should automatically connect, and hopefully assign DNS, etc.***

[image]

Comment: This works, but it's strange. The wired connection doesn't show up and the wireless won't work unless the cable has been plugged in. After connecting successfully to 192.168.100.252, I was able to configure the Airlive as a Universal Repeater but with dismal performance... but that's another question methinks.